# how to get list based on group id

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a group_id assigned to the user but at my users index page I want to how users that belong to the specific group that the logging user belongs to. 
currently its set to show all users

```
public function index() {

                            $this->User->recursive = 0;
                            $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
}
```

how would I change that

login:

```
public function login() {
     if ($this->request->is('post')){
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your username or password was incorrect.');
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: How are the users being logged in?

Comment: added login function to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the group_id of the currently logged in user, update the index() action to include:

```
public function index() {

    // get logged in user info
    $user = $this->Auth->user();
    $group_id = $user['group_id'];

    // add pagination conditions
    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array('User.group_id' => $group_id)
    );
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate('User'));

}
```

Hope that helps.